# Programmatically cancelling local notification

Tags: codenameone

This is on android. I am creating a local notification as follows:

```
public final static String ONGOING_CALL = "ONGOING_CALL";

 public static void displayOngoingCallNotification(String calleeNames,String msg) {
        try {
            LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
            n.setId(ONGOING_CALL);
            n.setAlertBody(msg);

            n.setAlertTitle("Calling "+calleeNames);

            Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
                    n,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, // fire date/time
                    LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE // Whether to repeat and what frequency
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and later on programmatically cancelling like:

```
public static void dismissOngoingCallNotification() {

        try {
            System.out.println("Going to dismiss ongoing call");
            Display.getInstance().cancelLocalNotification(ONGOING_CALL);
            System.out.println("ongoing call dismissed");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Trouble, can't dismiss ongoing call");

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

However, the notification still sticks on until I manually tap it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

[Local notifications](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#scheduleLocalNotification-com.codename1.notifications.LocalNotification-long-int-) are timed event, in this case the timed event got canceled after it already occurred. I don't think we have a way in the new notification framework to remove the visual notice of an already elapsed notification.